# Different ways to instantiate an NSManagedObject instance

Tags: core-data

As a CoreData beginner, I have so far found three different ways to instantiate an instance of an NSManagedObject:

```
1:
let myEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("MyEntity", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)!
let instance = MyEntity(entity: myEntity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
instance.someProperty = someValue
try! managedContext.save()

2:
let myEntity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("MyEntity",
inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

let instance = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
instance.setValue(someValue, forKey: "someProperty")
try! managedContext.save()

3:
let instance = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("MyEntity", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext) as! MyEntity
instance.somePropery = someValue
try! managedContext.save()
```

Are there any notable difference between these methods ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First two methods identical. In both cases you using same `NSManagedObject` init method.

Documentation of `NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(_ entityName: String, inManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext)` says that this method is "conceptually similar to" `NSManagedObject.init(entity entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext?)`

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEntityDescription/insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:

So, you can use any method that convenience for you.